# При нажатии на CardView открывался фрагмент с данными

Tags: android, android-fragment

Подскажите пожалуйста имеестя RecycleView a в нем CardView нужно при нажатии на cardView что б открывался фрагмент с данными про аквариумную рыбку, их около 100 видов, если создать 100 фрагментов то.я.просто запутаюсь я правильно понимаю нужно создать класси туда передавать текст и картинку с SQLite batabase

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

1. Вам нужно создаь всего один фрагмент.
2. В него при создании передавайте ID рыбы в БД. Делается это через `Fragment#setArguments(Bundle args)`
3. В `onCreate` фрагмента вытащите `ID` из аргументов (см п.2) и сделайте запрос в БД на предмет всей инфы о рыбе.
4. Отобразите инфу о рыбе